# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract, java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse

Tags: java, sorting, exception

```
class Solution {
    public int[] frequencySort(int[] nums) {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i : nums) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        list = fun(list);
        for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
            nums[i] = list.get(i);
        }
        return nums;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Integer> fun(ArrayList<Integer> list){
        Map<Integer,Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        
        list.forEach(i -> {
            map.put(i,map.getOrDefault(i,0)+1);
        });
        
        Collections.sort(list,(n1,n2) -> {
            int freq1 = map.get(n1);
            int freq2 = map.get(n2);
            
            if(freq1!=freq2){
                return freq1-freq2;
                // if(freq1>freq2){
                //     return 1;
                // }
                // return -1;
            }
            return n2-n1;
            //if(n1>=n2){
            //   return -1;
            //}
           // return 1;
            
        } );
        return list;
    }
}

//sample input : nums = [2,3,1,3,2]
//output : [1,3,3,2,2]
```

In the fun method, at Collections.sort(), I'm sorting an array based on increasing order of frequency, if both has same frequency then I add them in increasing order of values. The above code works fine which I get from google, but myself I have written almost similar code, which I have included as comments. Both code looks similar but my code(as comments) only passed 85/150 test cases after that I'm getting "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!"

I found similar questions but I can't understand that, Anyone explain it in simpler terms!!!

```
//This block I found in google

if(freq1!=freq2){
    return freq1-freq2;
 }
 return n2-n1;
```

```
//Below Block gives "Comparison method violates its general contract"

if(freq1!=freq2){
       if(freq1>freq2){
          return 1;
        }
       return -1;
}
if(n1>=n2){
       return -1;
}
return 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The last block you have given as an example of contract violation is wrong because of the following reason.

If, for example, we have two elements `a = (5, 1)` and `b = (5, 1)`, where I represent each element as a tuple of `(freq, n)`, then comparing `a` and `b` returns `-1` designating that `a` must go earlier than `b` in the sorted list. However, if we compare these two values in the opposite order -- `b` and `a`, the given example would still return `-1`, this time saying that `b` must go earlier than `a`.

I believe that explicitly taking care of returning `0` for the case when both `freq` and `n` are equal should fix the last piece of code.